# What can I do if the candidates running in local/State elections do not have a opinion on the issues I care about?

Tags: united-states, voting

What can I do if the candidates running in local/State elections do not have a opinion on the issues I care about?

I still want to cast a meaningful vote on the candidate most likely caring about my issues.

For example I thought that e-mailing them and asking them what they think about XYZ might be a good idea?

But then, if they were to win my vote, all the competitors would say Yes to what I want, and then again I would have no idea who to choose.

The way I do it right now is that I pick people based on whether they're supporting infrastructure that I live near, and if they're in favor of building an obscure bridge 80 miles away from me, then I say no because it would be a waste of my tax dollars.

Comment: We can't answer this for you, you have to decide. You could try to get an answer, you could decide based on what you *do*  know about them ... but do try to think beyond yourself when evaluating projects. Just because *you* won't use a bridge doesn't mean their other constitutents won't ...

Comment: There is no right or wrong way to decide how to vote. You can choose a candidate based on whatever metric you want and nobody can say you are wrong.  I've voted to close as "opinion based"

Comment: "all the competitors would say Yes to what I want" Don't tell them what you want, just ask what they would do and give them some options like, would you spent tax dollars on a new hospital, a new school or a new road. And only one of these is what you want. Problem solved.

Comment: It seems a bit singleminded to vote only based on what infrastructure benefits you directly.  There are a lot more issues at play; for example, do you consider things such as economics (including issues such as inflation, jobs, and wages), social issues such as social justice and abortion (on either side of the issue), religious freedom, etc?  A political party would be irresponsible to not have a published stance on at least most of these issues, even if they don't have a specific stance on whether to build a bridge in your city.

Comment: Expanding on @trilarion said, there are questions you can ask that elicit a response that is not a binary yes/no response.   For example, the question "If it is sunny tomorrow, would you go to the beach?" demands either a yes or no response.  However, the question "What do you want to do tomorrow if the weather is sunny?" prompts the speaker to return a non-binary choice and will better inform you of his opinion.  Then you can tell if you want to vote on him because he is pro-beach or if you'll vote for the other guy because he's one of those un-American  Moutain hikers!

Comment: Voted to reopen as the question is not opinioned based, (in fact OP took steps to remove any specific issue or their opinion on the issue) and a valid question about participation in the political process.

Answer (score 3):

Look at their personal character, their background, their positions on other issues which may suggest their views on the issue you care about, and look at who is supporting each of the candidates in their campaigns.

Ask someone who is more knowledgable about the candidates about whom they prefer and why.

If you truly have no information that makes you think that one candidate is better than another (which is more common in non-partisan local races in smaller local governments that get little media coverage, than in partisan state and local races), you can always refrain from casting a vote for that office entirely.

In partisan races, keep in mind that the most important thing, as a practical matter, may be which political party ends up with majority control of the government, rather than the individual positions of particular candidates, which often aren't realized anyway if they conflict with the majority sentiment of the political party that holds a majority.

Answer (score 2):

Like you have the right to vote, you also have the right to *not* vote. This is just as valid a practice of Democracy.

Comment: Government is like pizza: If you don't vote for the toppings you like, sometimes you end up with pineapple.  If you don't want pineapple on your pizza, you should speak up and say so.

Comment: @Ertai87, Voting for something or someone you don't support gives credence and a false sense to those you voted for that they actually do have that support, and perhaps even have a mandate. That is not only grossly inaccurate, it is possibly dangerous. Perhaps even immoral. This is why there are often boycotts of elections around the world. This is why many of us independents (in America) often don't vote for partisan candidates and have a much lower participation rate overall in elections. It is rationally better to not vote, than to vote for that which you unequivocally don't support.

Comment: @Ertai87, To borrow your analogy, in America our options are generally (even supported by the laws of the states) only Democrats and Republicans. Well if my voting options are only for pineapple on my pizza and for pineapple on my pizza, then I'd rather just go hungry. I'm never voting for pineapple. Ever. That's Democracy.

Comment: I look at it a different way.  Using the US example, you have 2 parties who are almost guaranteed to win every election.  No matter what you, personally, do, one of those 2 parties will win.  Those 2 parties have at least 1 issue which makes them different from one another (in the US the Republicans and Democrats have many issues which divide them, I'm sure, but let's say there's only 1); if they're running on exactly the same platform on every issue then why are they even different parties?  So, even if they agree on every single issue except one, you can vote on that one issue.

Comment: Then, even if you hate the outcome on every other issue, at least you won't hate the outcome on that one issue if the party you voted for wins.  Unfortunately, as I've discussed on other questions, you can't have a stable voting system (where you have a government that is not at constant risk of collapse) and also a voting system which respects many differing points of view, at the same time.  For an example of a voting system which has the latter, take a deep dive into the civics of Israel and Japan.